# Bring event to one line?

Tags: c#, events

When the user clicks a button, this events are activated:

```
flightWindow.SendAirplaneLand += onAirplaneStartSend; 
flightWindow.SendAirplaneTakeOff += onAirplaneTakeOffSend;
flightWindow.SendAirplaneChangeRoute += onAirplaneChangeRouteSend;
```

And they all call different methods to add info to a list:

```
public void onAirplaneStartSend(object sender, Land e)
    {
        listBoxFlightEvents.Items.Add(e.LandStatus);
    }

    public void onAirplaneTakeOffSend(object sender, TakeOff e)
    {
        listBoxFlightEvents.Items.Add(e.TakeOffStatus);
    }

    public void onAirplaneChangeRouteSend(object sender, ChangeRoute e)
    {
        listBoxFlightEvents.Items.Add(e.ChangeRouteStatus);
    }
```

My problem is that I want to bring all this info to one line of text to add to the list and I'm looking for a simple solution how to do this?

One way could be to let the methods return a string and put togehter a string of all returning string values and then add it to the list like this:

```
public string onAirplaneStartSend(object sender, Land e)
    {
        return e.LandStatus;
    }
```

But his is perhaps not possible and not convenient?

Comment: Is this a custom button?

Comment: This can work when you have a lot of repetition. Every control has an `object Tag` property. You could store an `Enum` there, and then you can have a single event, in which you cast the `sender` back to Control, you cast its Tag property to your enum type`. Should that fail, you either ignore and noop or throw an exception - depends on your design. This is a somewhat hidden approach, but you do not have to set the Tags in the Designer manually - you should do so in code soon after `InitializeComponent()`. You could even use T4 transform to generate a third partial class from text file somewher

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
flightWindow.SendAirplaneLand += (s,e) => {
  OnAirplaneStatusChange(e.LandStatus);
};
flightWindow.SendAirplaneTakeOff += (s,e) => {
  OnAirplaneStatusChange(e.TakOffStatus);
};
flightWindow.SendAirplaneChangeRoute += (s,e) => {
  OnAirplaneStatusChange(e.ChangeRouteStatus);
};

private void OnAirplaneStatusChange(string status)
{
  listBoxFlightEvents.Items.Add(status);
}
```

Although I'm still not entirely sure what you're going for. Unless the `Land`, `TakeOff` and `ChangeRoute` all inherit some common (e.g.) `AirplaceEventArgs` (and a common property denoting status) you'll have to bind them separately. Best case is use a generic `EventArgs` method, but you'll need to cast in some fashion to get `LandStatus`, `TakeOffStatus` and `ChangeRouteStatus` values.

I'd recommend:

```
public class AirplaneEventArgs : EventArgs
{
  public string Status { get; set; }
}
public class TakeOffEventArgs : AirplaneEventArgs
{
  /* other properties */
}
public class LandEventArgs : AirplaneEventArgs
{
  /* other properties */
}
public ChangeRouteEventArgs : AirplaneEventArgs
{
  /* other properties */
}
```

Then you can bind simply:

```
flightWindow.SendAirplaneLand += OnAirplaneStatusChange; 
flightWindow.SendAirplaneTakeOff += OnAirplaneStatusChange;
flightWindow.SendAirplaneChangeRoute += OnAirplaneStatusChange;

private void OnAirplaneStatusChange(object sender, AirplaneEventArgs e)
{ 
    // they all now share "Status" proeprty so no need to cast to
    // get "LandStatus" vs. "ChangeRouteStatus" vs. "TakeOffStatus"
    // values.
    listBoxFlightEvents.Items.Add(e.Status);
}
```

Comment: Thank you @asawyer, saw it on last revision. ;-)

Comment: Anytime, I was was typing up pretty much this as well. The question is kind of to vague though to know if this is what they want for sure.

Comment: Thansk for your answer! I didn't thought it had to be soo "complicated", but I'm going to try it